# Problems with generics / system architecture using generics

Tags: java, generics, architecture

Maybe I am having some problems understanding generics, but I can't do something that looks logical to me. Maybe you can clarify it for me.

I am developing a Java Library and there is a function that will call a platform that will return information in the JSON format. I wanted to create a namespace responsible for retrieving and parsing the JSON information into business objects. To do that, I created this:

JSON class - Has 2 methods:

```
protected JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url)
```

open the stream and download the JSON file

```
public <T, U extends Parser> T readObjectFromUrl(String url, U parser)
```

is the "entry point". Will call the readJsonFromUrl, and call the returned value to the parser.

The Parser class is an abstract class and has this interface

```
public abstract class Parser {

public abstract <T> T parse(JSONObject jsonObject);
}
```

What I wanted to do is to create a subclass that overrides the parse method, each subclass would return a different type.
For instance, a contact list parser would look like this:

```
public <T> T parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
ContactList contactList = new ContactList();

    //Simplified for clearness
    contactList = parse(jsonObject);

return contactList;
}
```

The problem is: I get a compiler error because it is expecting a T, and not a contactList.
If I change to , the signature of the new method do not match the signature of the parent class.
If I change the contactList's declaration to `T contactList;`, I can't call some methods I need (for instance addContact).

Am I getting generics wrong? Are they suited for what I want in this case?
If they are not, how would you implement a similar functionality?

Thanks,
Oscar

Edit: is the best solution to use Object instead of generics? It doesn't seem so pretty :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using generics on a method which returns always the same type of Objects, and that type may vary depending on the **implementation** of the method.

Then I guess you should move your generic declaration to the class.

```
public abstract class Parser<T> {
    public abstract T parse(JSONObject jsonObject);
}
```

And your implementation will look like :

```
public class Impl extends Parser<ContactList>{
    public abstract ContactList parse(JSONObject jsonObject){
        ContactList contactList = new ContactList();
        //Simplified for clearness
        contactList = parse(jsonObject);
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at how Google Guice implements the [Injector](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/inject/Injector.java).getInstance method:

```
<T> T getInstance(Class<T> type);
```

This allows the user to write:

```
ContactList contactList = injector.getInstance(ContactList.class);
```

Applying this pattern to your parser, I would think that you could make it possible to avoid the need to create different parser classes for each type you want to parse. Instead, you could just have a single Parser class, and call a method like this:

```
ContactList contactList = parser.parse(jsonObject, ContactList.class);
```

Comment: This looks like a very interesting approach, but I will have to learn about injection before doing that ,)
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Oscar: You don't need to worry about the injection aspect. Just use reflection to instantiate an object of the type that you're given as an argument. (This is assuming, of course, that the type has a "default" (no-argument) constructor.) The key is that the method signature is set up in such a way that you don't have to do any casting. It uses generics, and should help you eliminate a lot of the boilerplate-style code that your current strategy uses.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if I am missing something.
In my JSON class (readObjectFromUrl mthod), I will call the Parser.parser method. 
Currently I receive a parser parameter in my readObjectFromUrl and this parser returns the expected object type. I am very sorry, but I don't see the big difference this change would bring, I think I didn't understand you

Comment: @Oscar: Your current solution requires you to create a new Parser implementation for each type of object (e.g. `ContactListParser`). This parser's code appears to just create an instance of your object (`new ContactList()`), call some other "parse" method, and return the object. However, all three of these steps could be accomplished generically, using reflection to construct the object. So you could avoid writing a different implementation for each type. Maybe I misunderstood, and your "parse" method was just some hand-waving to indicate that you would be writing a bunch of other code there?

Comment: @Oscar: The `gson` library by google does what I'm trying to describe. See an example here: (http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).  Have you considered using it, rather than writing your own custom parsing implementations for each object type?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yes, actually I would populate the my object's properties inside the parse method, so I could return a useful business object from my method :) I will take a look in your link! (ps: sorry, I can't upvote your answers more than once :( )